# Area point filling algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I want to create a system that, given an input array of 2d or 3d points and a min/max distance between the points would connect them if they are "in-range" or create additional "missing" points in between so that there would be at least one "in-range" connection between all points.

I am wondering if there is any existing algorithm that is made to do so optimally?

**Edit**

Optimally in my case meaning that the algorithm fits the requirements the best way.

The requirements in my case are:

- New points should have at least 2 connections to other points
- New points should be in min/max range from other points
- As little as possible new points should be created (with minimum & maximum number specified).

Comment: "optimally" means what exactly? Minimum number of added points?

Comment: @Henry Optimally, meaning that it fits the requirements the best way. It can be minimum amount or maximum amount possible or something else that defines the rules. For example, if the minimum amount is 5 then it should be as close to 5 as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but that does not answer my question. What does it mean in this particular problem. Or asked differently what are the requirements?

Comment: @Henry In my application the requirements are that the algorithm should create minimum amount of new points (with minimum amount specified), and to stay in range of min/max distance from other points. Each new point should also be connected to at least 2 other points (otherwise there would be no reason to create them after all)

Comment: @Henry I will update the question to be more clear

Comment: I don't think that an algorithm to solve such a specific problem would be given a name, because it is indeed too specific. You can have a look at the kd-tree data structure, which would be very helpful in order to find "neighbors". Then, when it comes to adding as little new points as possible, that problem seems hard to solve to me if your distances are euclidian (with manhattan distances, linear programming would do a great job to solve it)

Comment: This is very similar to the Steiner tree problem which, unfortunately, is NP-hard.